# OVH cloud web setup proxy

Tags: proxy, cloud, middleware, ovh

I have a React project which uses an external API.
If I don't use a middleware proxy, I get the following error: 'has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. And today I wanted to put it online on OVH cloud web, the problem is that I don't have the possibility of setting up a proxy, so I said there was varnish but I can't configure it at all. Could you tell me a bit more about this? Knowing that I would like all requests from my application that go to /api to be redirected to urlapi.com

Answer (score 0):

Hummm so many questions in the same post ;-)

- the CORS you’re getting might be cause by your request (the error is saying you can’t specific the content type).
- You may setup varnish to proxy/cache you’re external API. But be aware that per default varnish is not re-resolving the DNS entries. So depending of the external API infrastructure setup, you might have downtime.
- as you may rewrite the request in varnish, you may specify or unspecify request headers (for example removing the content type header for option requests) but I you have to code varnish configuration specifically for it
- with varnish you may proxying the http requests from yourwebsite/api to api.external.com/whatever, anyhow varnish is very efficient for caching content. If your website is dealing with authorizations or cookies, you have to work around to get cache on it. If you’re not aiming caching the external API contents, a simple Apache proxy rule or a nginx backend might be easier to implement.

Good luck